Can I create multiple ajax function/request with same action and nonce within WordPress?
Can I create multiple ajax function/request with same action and nonce?
I created an array, and using that array, a new form and its fields will be generated. I want to use the same nonce and action for the AJAX function/request.
<?php

echo '<div class="forms_wrapper">';
foreach ($sections as $section) :
   echo '<form action="#" method="POST" class="save_settings_form">';
   wp_nonce_field('settings_save_nonce', 'settings_save_nonce');

   echo '<input name="name" id="name" value="" />';
   echo '<input name="email" id="email" value="" />';
  
   //some more fields
   echo '<button>submit</button>';
   echo '</form>';
endforeach;

echo '</div>';

Ajax
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_settings_save_nonce', array($this, 'settings_save_nonce'));
function settings_save_nonce()
{
   if (!isset($_POST['settings_save_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce(sanitize_key(wp_unslash($_POST['settings_save_nonce'])), 'settings_save_nonce')) {
      return;
   }
   //Some functions

   wp_die();
}

jQuery
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".save_settings_form").on("submit", function (e) {
    let task = $(this).serialize();
    task += "&action=settings_save_nonce";

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ajax_url,
      data: task,
      success: function (response) {},
    });
  });
});


Yes, you can use the same AJAX action and nonce for multiple AJAX requests in WordPress. Your current setup looks good for what you want to achieve.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.save_settings_form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission

        let task = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize the form data
        task += "&action=settings_save_nonce"; // Append the action

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_url,
            data: task,
            success: function(response) {
                // Handle the response as needed
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    });
});

Since you're generating multiple forms, ensure that the AJAX request correctly identifies which form is being submitted. You might want to include additional data in the serialized string if necessary.
